# .htaccess redirect all directories and subdomains to http://domain.com/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've scoured Google and stackoverflow for a solution to this problem. Hopefully somebody here can help. I have an old website that I am no longer using. I would like all requests 301 redirected to http://example.com/ using .htaccess. That includes requestas such as:

```
- http://whatever.example.com/
- http://example.com/whatever
- http://whatever.example.com/whatever
```

I have tried a few ideas I found online, but either they won't redirect both subdomains and directories, or they result in infinite loops.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Seems obvious, but I think I should mention that I am using "example.com" in place of my real domain, I don't really want requests redirected to example.com :)

Comment: Will need to see the structure of you website, how your sub domains are set up and are there multiple .htaccess files inside each directory. If you have .htaccess in multiple directories you will have to edit each.

Comment: I last used subdomains on that site many years ago. Right now all subdomains resolve to the same directory on my server. So, for example: whatever.example.com, www.example.com, and example.com all point to the same public_html folder on my server. I presume that a .htaccess file that says essentially the following will work: IF request NOT http://example.com/ THEN 301 to http://example.com/. I just don't know how to code that in .htaccess. Thanks :)

Comment: BTW, the real url is http://socialenigma.com/. I just wanted to avoid being spammy in my initial question.

Comment: Try these rules:
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com 
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Virendra.

This is what I have now, and it works. The first condition and rule make sure the file being requested isn't `/robots.txt` and then 301 to http://socialenigma.com/. The second condition and rule check that the host is `socialenigma.com` (without any subdomain) and, if not, 301 to http://socialenigma.com/.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(robots\.txt).*$
RewriteRule . http://socialenigma\.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^socialenigma\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://socialenigma\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It seems that this isn't as efficient as it could be. Maybe someone can help condense these rules.